# Aggregation function with the inner join on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5 tables (A,B,C,D). All are inner joined and used to display data. Another table E has the column sourceId which has reference in column A. I need to show the count of occurrence in the main query. For example:

```
A.*,B.*,C.*,D.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.BId= B.Id
INNER JOIN C
ON A.CId = C.Id
INNER JOIN D
ON A.Did= D.Id
```

E table can contain 2 or 1 or 0 records referencing to table A. I need to display count of the occurrence in the above query and sort accordingly from 0 to 2. Can some one help me writing this up? I am not sure how should I go ahead with aggregation function over here.
Output should look like this:

```
E.Count|A.*|B.*|C.*|D.*|
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tag. MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products, and T-SQL is specifically the dialect for SQL Server.[Edit] your question to tag properly, and only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Seems like you should be using a correlated subquery. How you do that, depends on the product you're using.

Comment: Sorry updated the tags. I am currently using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select A.*,B.*,C.*,D.*,E_count
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.BId= B.Id
INNER JOIN C ON A.CId = C.Id
INNER JOIN D ON A.Did= D.Id
outer apply (
   select count(*) as E_count
   from E
   where E.sourceId = A.Id 
) E
```

or

```
select A.*,B.*,C.*,D.*,E_count
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.BId= B.Id
INNER JOIN C ON A.CId = C.Id
INNER JOIN D ON A.Did= D.Id
left join (
   select count(*) as E_count
   from E
   group by E.sourceId 
) E on E.sourceId = A.Id
```

Comment: Also a lateral join cannot reference columns external to the subquery..

Comment: `APPLY` isn't a `JOIN` nor works like a lateral join, it's a correlated subquery.

Comment: isn't `apply` sql server syntax for `lateral join`?

Comment: My understanding is that a lateral join would be like you initially had; `LEFT JOIN ({Sub query})` When doing that, the sub query *cannot* reference columns outside of the subquery (unlike a correlated subquery you have here).